# Audio is not working properly

Tags: linux, debian, drivers, audio, realtek

I am running Debian 11. I had trouble getting to use my headset mic and audio at the same time. I found some errors while executing a command for `initframs` (not for this matter) and I saw I was missing some Realtek firmware(that's my onboard mobo soundcard). So,then I got realtek firmware installed using `sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek` ,after I rebooted I could see two more options.I used `Stereo Duplex` and it worked untill I rebooted my PC,and now I am back at the initial part.I don't have these options and the package is installed.What should I do?

Edit:

Here is the output of: `sudo dmesg -H |grep snd_`

```
[  +0.000007] snd_hda_intel 0000:26:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[  +0.000078] snd_hda_intel 0000:28:00.4: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[  +0.003414] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig for ALC892: line_outs=4 (0x14/0x15/0x16/0x17/0x0) type:line
[  +0.000002] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[  +0.000001] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[  +0.000001] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[  +0.000001] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
[  +0.000001] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Front Mic=0x19
[  +0.000001] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Rear Mic=0x18
[  +0.000001] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Line=0x1a
```

Also I get the same output by running : `journalctl -xb |grep snd`

I also grep-ed this one in case it's helpful `journalctl -xb |grep Audio`

```
Mar 03 11:26:26 Deb-PC kernel: ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Mar 03 11:26:26 Deb-PC kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:28:00.4/sound/card1/input30
Mar 03 11:26:26 Deb-PC kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:28:00.4/sound/card1/input31
Mar 03 11:26:26 Deb-PC kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:28:00.4/sound/card1/input32
Mar 03 11:26:26 Deb-PC kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Line Out Front as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:28:00.4/sound/card1/input33
Mar 03 11:26:26 Deb-PC kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Line Out Surround as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:28:00.4/sound/card1/input34
Mar 03 11:26:26 Deb-PC kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Line Out CLFE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:28:00.4/sound/card1/input35
Mar 03 11:26:26 Deb-PC kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Line Out Side as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:28:00.4/sound/card1/input36
Mar 03 11:26:26 Deb-PC kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:28:00.4/sound/card1/input37
Mar 03 11:26:28 Deb-PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[909]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Front Mic (/dev/input/event19)
Mar 03 11:26:28 Deb-PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[909]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Rear Mic (/dev/input/event20)
Mar 03 11:26:28 Deb-PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[909]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Line (/dev/input/event21)
Mar 03 11:26:28 Deb-PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[909]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Line Out Front (/dev/input/event22)
Mar 03 11:26:28 Deb-PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[909]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Line Out Surround (/dev/input/event23)
Mar 03 11:26:28 Deb-PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[909]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Line Out CLFE (/dev/input/event24)
Mar 03 11:26:28 Deb-PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[909]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Line Out Side (/dev/input/event25)
Mar 03 11:26:28 Deb-PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[909]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone (/dev/input/event26)
Mar 03 11:26:39 Deb-PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1425]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Front Mic (/dev/input/event19)
Mar 03 11:26:39 Deb-PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1425]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Rear Mic (/dev/input/event20)
Mar 03 11:26:39 Deb-PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1425]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Line (/dev/input/event21)
Mar 03 11:26:39 Deb-PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1425]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Line Out Front (/dev/input/event22)
Mar 03 11:26:39 Deb-PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1425]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Line Out Surround (/dev/input/event23)
Mar 03 11:26:39 Deb-PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1425]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Line Out CLFE (/dev/input/event24)
Mar 03 11:26:39 Deb-PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1425]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Line Out Side (/dev/input/event25)
Mar 03 11:26:39 Deb-PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1425]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone (/dev/input/event26)
```

.

Comment: You could start by checking the logs, with `journalctl -xb` and/or `sudo dmesg -H`, and looking for any messages containing `snd_`. The `firmware-realtek` package contains firmware for Realtek ethernet, WiFi and Bluetooth adapters only; it should have nothing to do with audio. You might also identify your motherboard model: if there is some model-specific trick you'll need, then someone else having the same motherboard might be able to help you. Please *edit your question* to add information.

Comment: Yeah,I figured out a little after that the Realtek package is not for audio. So,that means it was a random thing that happened after I rebooted. I also have noticed that like 1 out of 5 times I reboot i will have a chance to get both my audio and mic working. I will update my post and include the output you mentioned for. For the motherboard part I couldn't find anything usefull. @telcoM

Comment: So you have a Realtek ALC892 sound chip... Try running `dmidecode -s system-product-name` or `dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name` as root; one or the other should produce something meaningful about your motherboard model.

Comment: Here's my mobo:
```dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name```
```B450 TOMAHAWK MAX (MS-7C02)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this "fixed". As telcoM suggested,this was probably a PulseAudio problem(could be that the devices have not yet initialliazed). So,the part about fixing it was a simple one. I had noticed that `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service` or `pulseaudio -k` was fixing my problem temporarily,so I just added `pulseaudio -k` in `~/.profile` . Also `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service` should work (not tested).

Note: adding a `crontab`(even user specific) won't work.
It should be executed by the `~/.profile` as soon as the user logs in,or otherwise after login the Audio devices would be broken again.
Hope this helps if anyone comes across this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Google finds several discussions about Realtek ALC892 and similar problems with it.

This video collects a lot of information:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68jOe2rh6jE

Based on it, try running `alsamixer -c 0`. It should bring up a terminal-based mixer display. In the top left corner it says which sound device it's currently adjusting: if it says anything other than `Card: HD-Audio Generic`, either press <kbd>F6</kbd> to select another sound device, or press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit and increment the number after the `-c` option to target another sound device.

When you see the `Card: HD-Audio Generic`, use arrow keys to move between the various items: unless your window is very wide, the display will probably scroll left/right as you hit the edges. Find the settings named "Auto-Mute" and "Loopback", and ensure they're both `Disabled` (use up/down arrows to toggle the settings).

Auto-Mute will normally silence the speakers whenever something is plugged in to the headphone connection. Switching off Auto-Mute will allow the headset and the speakers both work at the same time. But if the Auto-Mute has already muted the speaker channel, you might have to unmute it manually by moving to it using left/right cursor keys and pressing <kbd>M</kbd> to toggle the Mute state. Note that you'll want to unmute the headphones/speakers at the `Playback` view (= default view, key <kbd>F3</kbd>) but the microphone at the `Capture` view (key <kbd>F4</kbd>).

You might also run `hdajacksensetest` (in package `alsa-tools`) and see if the results look sensible. If it says `present = No` for an audio jack you know is actually connected, the jack sense map in the system BIOS might be incorrect. You can then use the `hdajackretask` (in package `alsa-tools-gui`) to override the BIOS-provided jack sense map. If you need to do that, you should try updating the system firmware (BIOS/UEFI) and see if that fixes the problem persistently. If not, then you should report your system/motherboard model and the `hdajackretask` options you needed to use to the Linux sound driver developers, so they can make future kernel versions apply the correction automatically.

For some Realtek chip models, [the driver](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/sound/pci/hda/patch_realtek.c?h=v5.10.103) supports a large number of `model=<something>` options for the `snd_hda_intel` kernel module. But for ALC892, the only supported option (in the 5.10 kernel of Debian 11 at least) seems to be [`model=asrock-mobo`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/sound/pci/hda/patch_realtek.c?h=v5.10.103#n10961), which gets [activated automatically for ASRock B150M](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/sound/pci/hda/patch_realtek.c?h=v5.10.103#n10866).  You might try that module option if you think your motherboard might be similar to ASRock B150M (i.e. designed by Asus/ASRock, and/or using the Intel B150 chipset).

---

If the problem can be remedied with a `pulseaudio -k` or `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service`, then the problem seems to be just that the PulseAudio daemon starts before all the sound devices are ready for it. In that case, adding explicit dependencies for the audio device to the PulseAudio user service might help.

First, you'll need to figure out the systemd device unit names for your audio devices. This command should output them:

```
systemctl --user | awk '/sound-/{ print $1; }'
```

For example, on my system, it will output three (long) device unit names, one per line:

```
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.0-0000:01:00.1-sound-card1-controlC1.device
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d4-1\x2d4.4-1\x2d4.4.1-1\x2d4.4.1:1.2-sound-card2-controlC2.device
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1f.3-sound-card0-controlC0.device
```

To test, I added a `~/.config/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service.d/override.conf` file (creating the `pulseaudio.service.d` directory first) with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Wants=sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.0-0000:01:00.1-sound-card1-controlC1.device
Wants=sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d4-1\x2d4.4-1\x2d4.4.1-1\x2d4.4.1:1.2-sound-card2-controlC2.device
Wants=sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1f.3-sound-card0-controlC0.device
After=sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.0-0000:01:00.1-sound-card1-controlC1.device
After=sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d4-1\x2d4.4-1\x2d4.4.1-1\x2d4.4.1:1.2-sound-card2-controlC2.device
After=sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1f.3-sound-card0-controlC0.device
```

This would make it explicit to `systemd` that those three sound devices are needed by the `pulseaudio.service`, and that the service should start only *after* those devices are ready.

You could do the same with your specific sound devices.

Disclaimer: since I have your problem in the first place, I cannot confirm that my suggestion works. By testing it, I could only prove that it was not harmful. But if this fix works, it should eliminate the actual root cause of the problem by preventing `pulseaudio.service` from starting too early, as opposed to working around it by forcibly restarting the service once.

If this fix works and you wish to make it effective for all users of your system, simply move the `override.conf` file to directory `/etc/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service.d/` instead (creating the directory as necessary).

Comment: I came across this video while trying to find a solution,but no luck. I have tried both ```alsamixer``` & ```hdajackretask```.I can't see anything wrong in the configurations. The "weird" think about it is that rebooting or logging might fix the problem. While rebooting some of the times,I noticed that this is not the only audio device that may not work. I have also HDMI audio,and after a reboot I got no audio(saying unplugged) while I didn't even change anything.For Realtek:if it's working correctly I get two more options.The one I use is Stereo Duplex.Thats the problem,that option dissapears

Comment: The "Stereo Duplex" is PulseAudio terminology, and it disappearing means PulseAudio thinks there is either no microphone or no speaker/headphones connected. So is there any difference in `dmesg -H |grep snd_` or `hdajacksensetest` results when Stereo Duplex is available vs. when it is not? Or if there is no difference, try `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service`.

Comment: Yes,that works.Also ```pulseaudio -k``` is working(i think it's similar),but I the problem persists with every reboot.

Comment: Aha! Then it seems to be exclusively a PulseAudio problem: perhaps PulseAudio starts before all audio devices have completed initializing. If so, there are several ways to fix the problem: you could force the relevant sound driver modules to load earlier in the boot process, or add an override file for the PulseAudio service to explicitly require that specific sound devices are present before PulseAudio is allowed to start. I'm on mobile, will write more later.

Comment: So,I might have a "fix". I tried some days ago the ```pulseaudio -k``` and I noticed that it was fixing my issue temporarily.I tried then to add a crontab with that command and adding a delay for 20 seconds before execution. That didn't work so I gave up. Now that you mentioned restarting pulseaudio,I gave it a try again with my previous attempt,but instead I used the ```~/.profile``` and it seems to be working(so far).I think using a crontab was not working because it was executing before I was even logged in. I noticed that it would break(sometimes)after my login.I will update if this works